# How jQuery-File-Upload plugin uploads files to server - each in one POST request or all in one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, post, upload

How [jQuery-File-Upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki) uploads files to server - each in one POST request or all in one? Is this any how configurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Options FAQ](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options/)

```
By default, each file of a selection is uploaded using an individual request for XHR type uploads.
Set this option to false to upload file selections in one request each.

Note: Uploading multiple files with one request requires the multipart option to be set to true (the default).

    Type: boolean
    Default: true
```